# IE11 - System.AccessViolationException on simple scroll

Tags: internet-explorer, crash, internet-explorer-11, access-violation

I have application being hosted on IE11 (with ActiveX), when I'm trying to activate a simple scroll the app crashes, the application **working well** on IE9,10

The exception is:

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll Additional information: Attempted to read or
>   write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory
>   is corrupt.

**On Event Viewer:**
First Error:

> Application: Web Agent.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException Stack:    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr,
>   Int32, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)    at
>   WebAgentShell.AgentForm.Main(System.String[])

Second Error:

> Faulting application name: Web Agent.exe, version: 6.1.1.171, time
>   stamp: 0x53d4dded Faulting module name: MSHTML.dll, version:
>   11.0.9600.17280, time stamp: 0x53f27d67 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0026e47c Faulting process id: 0x329c Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cfe6b8e7e1ffcb Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CosmoCom\6.1.1\Enhanced Web Agent\Web Agent.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSHTML.dll Report Id:
>   603b6e66-52ac-11e4-8e19-38eaa7fc5cea